# How to convert Arduino MQ-3 input to Delphi Interfaces?

Tags: delphi, arduino

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tguWr.png)

For software breath detection of alcohol in delphi,Try to share for as a reference final project?

Comment: Get some serial port library and wait for receiving lines.

Comment: It Can But Changed Letters Become Integer MQ-3 Arduino How to send to delphi ...

Comment: If you mean the first line `Serial.println(value)`, it still sends ASCII text no matter which overload is called (see [println](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Println)). You receive that value as string line and convert it to integer. Which serial port library do you use?

Comment: Welcome to SO read this, please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For link creation arduino + MQ3 + Delphi where?

Comment: Have you received anything from serial port?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions asking us to find or recommend off-site resources (including links to references) are off-topic here. Please take some time to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages, particularly [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: Seems you are missing a basic copy pasting skill.

Comment: How to get past?

Answer (score 1):

The data you are sending is just ASCII text followed by <kbd>CR</kbd>+<kbd>LF</kbd>, so it's expectable that if you call the overload passing an integer value, that value is received as text. See the [**println**](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Println) reference:

> **println**
>
> Prints data to the serial port as human-readable ASCII text followed
>   by a carriage return character (ASCII 13, or '\r') and a newline
>   character (ASCII 10, or '\n').

So get some serial port library and wait there for <kbd>CR</kbd>+<kbd>LF</kbd> chars which will indicate complete text. For instance with [**TurboPower Async**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tpapro/), you could setup **TApdDataPacket** component this way:

```
ApdDataPacket1.StartCond := scAnyData;
ApdDataPacket1.EndCond := [ecString];
ApdDataPacket1.EndString := #13#10;
```

And in its **OnStringPacket** event process the received text somehow:

```
procedure TForm1.ApdDataPacket1StringPacket(Sender: TObject; Data: string);
begin
  { even an integer value sent by println method will be received as text
    which naturally opens the door for creating some simple communication
    protocol, so let's just log this time; with function like TryStrToInt
    you could test if the received text is an integer value, but it still
    is not a real communication protocol }
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Data);
end;
```

Comment: Link for the manufacture of Alcohol Sensor MQ-3 Arduino Interfaces Delphi ....
I beg?

Comment: @thaliamamentu Why ask us? Why not ask the manufacturer? It's extremely unlikely that you will find free code, already written in Delphi, for your precise project. Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service.

Comment: value= analogRead(AOUTpin);//reads the analaog value from the alcohol sensor's AOUT pin
  Serial.println(value);
 if(value<200)
  {
      Serial.println("Kamu Sadar");
  }
  if (value>=200 && value<280)
  {
      Serial.println("Alkohol Terdeteksi");
  }

Comment: How to convert it into integer how it will send in delphi